# Algorithm to finding shortest sequence of numbers from array A that add up to number B

Tags: algorithm

I had an interesting interview question the other day that sort of stumped me. I couldn't find a really good answer for it. The problem stated:

> Suppose you are given a number *B* and an array *A* of length n. The number B is a natural number, and all numbers in array *A* are distinct, natural numbers. Design an algorithm that would find the shortest sequence of numbers in array *A* that would sum up to the number *B*. Duplicates can be used.

So, as an example, let us say I have a number `B = 19`, and `A = [9, 6, 3, 1]`. I could say a solution is `6+6+6+1`, or `3+3+3+3+3+3+1`, but the solution they are looking for is `9+9+1`, because that is the shortest sequence of numbers.

The algorithm that I designed would sort the array and reach into the largest number and subtract it from the original number. It would keep doing this until it could no longer subtract the largest number. It would then go through the array and see if it could keep finding any numbers that it could subtract from B. It actually looked a lot like this:

```
def domath(b, a):
    a.sort()
    x = []
    n = 0
    idx = -1
    while b != 0:
        n = a[idx]
        if(b >= n):
            b -= n
            x.append(n)
        else:
            idx -= 1
    return x
```

But this solution would not always work. It would only work if you were lucky enough to have, say, a 2 or a 1 in the array, or the numbers that you kept subtracting from b magically worked. Consider if `B=21` and `A=[7,8,9]`. If it kept subtracting 9, it would not be able to find a solution.

So I was thinking "Okay, then maybe I need to backtrack a bit.".

If I reached into the `x` array, which keeps track of all the number we kept subtracting, I could add the latest number we subtracted from `b`, then try to move the idx to the *next* largest number. So, instead of doing 21 - 9, then 12 -9, it would do 21 - 9, then 12 - 8. It still wouldnt find anything, so then it would try 21 - 9, then 12 - 7. It still wouldnt find anything, so it would try 21 - 8, then 13 - 8, and it wouldnt find anything, so it would do 21 -8, then 13 -7, and it still wouldn't find anything, so it would try 21 -7, and continue on that, and determine if it could do it. If it cant (in this case, it should), it would just return "False" or something.

Is that... a good solution? I feel like there must be a better one, because the interviewers were kind of iffy about this solution.

Comment: Does your method return as soon as it finds a valid solution? If so, I don't think you will always find the shortest sequence. What about A=8, B=[6, 4, 1]?

Comment: A hint for the solution: you can write a clear and correct solution recursively, but a little trick is needed to make it computationally efficient. (@John Lexus I can tell you the magic words to google if you want, but if you might prefer to think about the hint first).

Comment: @myrtlecat exactly, which is why I think my whole solution is wrong to begin with. The backtrracking method would work, but I think that makes it pretty complex. I don't know.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem ?

Comment: This is a really weird use of the word 'sequence'

Answer (score 0):

Tricky. The linked wikipedia page suggests an approach that will take I think O (B * length (A)) which would take quite long if we had B = 1,000,000,000,000 instead of B = 21 with A = [9, 8, 7]. Your backtracking algorithm would handle this reasonably quickly if you start with a division:

```
111,111,111,111 nines leaves one, no way. 
111,111,111,110 nines leaves ten, no way (trying 1 or 0 eights)
111,111,111,109 nines leaves 19, no way (trying 2, 1 or 0 eights)
111,111,111,108 nines leaves 28 = 4x7 (trying 3 .. 0 eights). Best so far.
111,111,111,107 nines leaves 37. 4x8 < 37, no solution can beat what we have.
```

In your example, B = 21, backtracking would also work quite well. If we just denote the numbers of nines, eights, and sevens, then you would just try the following: 2,0,0; 1,1,0; 1,0,1; 0,2,0; 0,1,1; 0,0,3.

You'd want to stop search branches when you have a solution and can prove that no further solution can be better. That's what I did: When you have 37 left and the highest number available is 8 then you need at least 5 numbers. And for every nine that you remove that number is going up at least by one, so the best solution so far cannot be beaten.